# Can't fix `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode`

Tags: webpack, fusioncharts, webpack-2

I have tried too many things:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-without-strict 
https://github.com/fancyboynet/babel-preset-es2015-without-strict/issues/1

```
     presets: [
   [
     "es2015",
     {
       strict: false,
      loose: true
    }
 ]
 ]
 ,"plugins": ["transform-remove-strict-mode"]
```

I am trying to load fusionchharts. everything works fine now, I am using angular and in some of html templates other charts is defined with `<script src=" path to chart">` now I want to build it with webpack, but constantly get this error, is there work around for such trouble?